# Dealing with Infinity Rational/Irrational Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have two questions which I think both concern the same problem I am having. Is  $...121212.0$ a rational number and is $....12121212....$ a rational number? The reason I was thinking it could be a number is when you take the number $x=0.9999...$, then $10x=9.999...$ . Therefore, we conclude $9x=9$ which means $x=1$. Why could or couldn't you do the same thing and divide the first number in similar fashion by defining it as $x$ and then taking $x/100$?

Comment: Do you mean that the number extends infinitely to the *left*? No, that's not a number in the usual sense. Dividing it does not manage to move the decimal point so that there are finitely many digits to the left of it.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. So is that number not a real number? Why is that number not a real number then? I thought the real numbers were defined as the numbers on the number line.

Comment: I was thinking about dividing it but why couldn't you let $x=...121212.0$, then $100x=...121200.0$. Therefore, $99x=-12$. Which means $x=-12/99$.

Comment: If it were a real number then such a manipulation would work, but it is not, because it is being defined as the limit of a sum that doesn't converge. Think intuitively for a second of what your manipulation did: whatever that thing is, it should be a *positive* number (it has no minus sign in its decimal expansion), yet however you do these shift-and-subtract manipulations you will find it is a *negative* number.

Comment: "Why is that number not a real number then? I thought the real numbers were defined as the numbers on the number line"  That thing you wrote is *not* on the number line.  Where would it fit?

Comment: And you have it backwords.  The "number line" is defined as a representation of the numbers.  The numbers came first.  The number line is a representation of the numbers.  Every point on the number line has a place.  Your "numbers" have no place because for any place, you "number" is over ten times larger.  That is if a place is roughly at $10^k$ you number is larger than $10^k$.  No matter what place we pick.  Your "number" is larger.  Your number does not fit on the number line.

Comment: I didn't want to write an answer, because I by no means have a complete grasp on this concept, but if you're willing to travel down the rabbit hole a little you may find the following interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number  It offers a method for giving meaning to the number you wrote. Whether or not we are still in the real number system is debatable.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 "Whether or not we are still in the real number system is debatable." No, it's not. While the $p$-adics are incredibly interesting and important, they are not real numbers. The phrase "real number" has a technical meaning, and it does not include the $p$-adics.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I posted another question if you could help me with it I would greatly appreciate it <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393709/definition-axioms-for-the-set-of-real-numbers-why-arent-p-adic-numbers-real-nu>. Its just that this concept is going to drive me nuts. If not, it is no big deal. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the clarification. I thought that that was what my statement already implied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write:

> I thought the real numbers were defined as the numbers on the number line.

This isn't really a definition of the real numbers, since "number line" is a bit vague, but: a key fact about the number line as generally understood is that the distance between any two points is finite. If I imagine a number with digits stretching infinitely far to the left, such a number is infinitely large, that is, infinitely far away from zero; and these don't have a place on the number line as generally understood.

This is not to say that we can't give a mathematically precise meaning to such objects! Indeed, one particular formalization of them - the [*$p$-adic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) - plays an important role in number theory and algebraic geometry (and they allow manipulations such as that in your last comment).  However, it's important to note that these are not, in fact, real numbers.

Put another way, while you can manipulate these expressions in an interesting way (e.g. conclude that $...99999=-1$), that does not in any way mean that they correspond to something *in the particular number system "the real numbers"*; rather, it merely suggests that they may be interesting objects in their own right. There are lots of very interesting objects (besides the $p$-adics mentioned above) that we can make sense of, which are not real numbers:

- [Square roots of negative numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)
- [Infinitesimals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis)
- [Non-zero numbers which, when squared, equal zero.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis)
- [Complex numbers but this time with even *more* square roots of negative numbers, because why quit when you're ahead.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)
- And, dearest to my heart, [various different kinds of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).

Comment: I like this answer the most, because it says that any two points along the numberline is finite.

Answer (score 2):

$0.a_0a_1a_2..... = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k*10^{-k} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_k*10^{-k}$.  This limit exists. For one thing the terms $a_k*10^{-k}$ get *small* and approach infinitesimal.  (But more importantly, the difference between the finite sums becomes infinitesimal.)

So this is a valid number.  It may or may not be rational.

$.....a_3a_2a_1.0$ if it were to mean anything would have to mean $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k*10^{k} = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_k*10^{k}$.  This limit does *NOT* exist. The terms $a*10^k$ get *large* infinitely and these do not converge to any finite number.

So this is not a number of any sort or any meaningful concept.

When numbers get infinitely *small* they approach $0$ and it is possible (but it doesn't always happen) that we can add them infinitely and have the limit exist (but it is important to realize there are exceptions). (Decimals, however, *can* be added infinitely and converge.  I won't go into details.)

When number get infinitely *large* they .... blow up.  They do not converge to anything but increase to infinite.  We can not *ever* add them infinitely and have the limit exist.

Answer (score 1):

The "numbers" you have written are not real numbers at all, so they are not rational or irrational.  The decimal expansion of a real number cannot continue infinitely to the left.  Why?  Well, intuitively, such a number would be "infinitely large" and there are no infinitely large real numbers.  More precisely, an expression like $...121212.0$ would denote the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cdot 10^n$$ where $a_n=2$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=1$ if $n$ is odd.  But this series diverges: the partial sums get larger and larger without bound, since you keep adding larger powers of $10$.  So there is no real number that is the sum of the series.