# Definition/Axioms for the Set of Real Numbers: Why Aren't P-Adic Numbers Real Numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Why aren't p-adic numbers real numbers? I found the definition of real numbers can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) on wikipedia which I put directly below for convenience. I think it would break the fact that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would have a least upper bound, but I am not quite sure. I am relatively new to this concept but any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Let ℝ denote the set of all real numbers. Then:
>
> - The set ℝ is a field, meaning that addition and multiplication are defined and have the usual properties.
> - The field ℝ is ordered, meaning that there is a total order ≥ such that, for all real numbers x, y and z:
>
>   - if x ≥ y then x + z ≥ y +
>       z;
>   - if x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 0 then xy ≥ 0.
> - The order is Dedekind-complete; that is: every non-empty subset S of ℝ with an upper bound in ℝ has a least upper bound (also called
>     supremum) in ℝ.

Comment: An ordered field contains $\mathbb{Q}, <$ and if it has the least upper bound property then it contains $\mathbb{R}$. As $\sqrt{p} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_p$, it doesn't contain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What would be $\mathbb{Q}_p \cap \mathbb{R}$ if it makes sense ? There is also  $\mathbb{Q}_p \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ which is useful.

Comment: just to be annoying I'll say that some p-adics are rationals which are real. So some p adic numbers are real numbers.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  I'm not sure that is really correct.  We often say that the rationals are contained in the reals, but that is actually a kind of sloppy use of language.  Really, the rationals are embedded into the reals in a way that preserves the structure of the rationals.  It would be more accurate to say that there are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ that are isometric to $\mathbb{Q}$ as fields.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Don't want to argue too much since you aren't misunderstanding anything here, but I think if it's "inaccurate" to call the image of said embedding "the rationals" we've gone a bit too far down the rabbit hole. It's not like the rationals, the reals, the integers or anything else refer to one specific construction in ch 1 of Rudin or wherever. I'll confess to being on shaky ground identifying the $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ with the $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q_p$, though (insert pointless philosophical argument here).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The issue is that you need to say that you're preserving the structure. I can say silly things like "$\mathbb{Z}$ is a field" by just bijecting $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ and transporting the operations. But that destroys all of $\mathbb{Z}$'s original structure. It's not really relevant here though because $\mathbb{Q}$ does indeed embed nicely into $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $p$-adic numbers are not ordered as a field.

The real numbers are the unique (up to isomorphism) totally ordered field that is Dedekind complete.  The $p$-adic numbers are a field for any prime $p$, but they will not be ordered and, as such, the notion of Dedekind completeness doesn't even really make sense.

On the other hand, we can build the $p$-adics as a *metric* completion of $\mathbb{Q}$.  From this point of view, the topologies of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ will be quite different---$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally disconnected (and topologically, indistinguishable from a Cantor set!).  Hence the $p$-adics differ from the reals from that point of view, as well.

On the other other hand, it is possible to show via Ostrowki's theorem, that the only non-trivial metric completions of the rationals are $\mathbb{R}$ and the $p$-adic completions.  Thus there is a relation between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Your help is appreciated. Why aren't they ordered though? I do not know why someone down voted this response. Do you use strong induction for the set of real numbers to show that they are not ordered?

Comment: @W.G. Wasn't the downvoter but I suspect the reason was that before an edit, the answer was only one sentence long.

Comment: Yeah, I was snarky, then regretted it.  The problem is that there is not an order on the $p$-adics that is compatible with the field structure, thus you cannot make a totally ordered field out of $\mathbb{Q}_p$---orderings and the field structure don't play nice together.  That being said, the difference in topology is, I think, easier to see and therefore more convincing.

Comment: @W.G. To clarify Xander's remark: we can *prove* that there is no way to define a notion of "positive" on the $p$-adics which "respects the field structure" (that is, positive $+$ positive $=$ positive, positive $\times$ positive $=$ positive, and for any nonzero number $a$ either $a$ is positive or $-a$ is positive and not both). This shows that the way multiplication and addition work in the $p$-adics is fundamentally different from how they work in the real numbers, since the real numbers *do* allow such a notion of "positive."